# mongoDB - Get sub string & convert string to number in group stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to sum the salary of employees via aggreagation in MongoDB, the issue is salary is preceeded by Currency Symbol `$`, and not able to get the total in group.

Sample Database entry :

```
{  
"_id" : ObjectId("5e2f408b1548343a74dce68a"),  
"employee_first_name" : "Gwenaëlle",  
"employee_last_name" : "Shawley",  
"department" : "Product Management",  
"salary" : "$205223.43",  
"years_in_job" : 17,  
"dob" : "4/12/1980",  
"childrenId" : [  
ObjectId("5e2da031c71c0b0f54e35236"),  
ObjectId("5e2da031c71c0b0f54e35234"),  
ObjectId("5e2da031c71c0b0f54e35235"),  
],  
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-02-06T16:47:29.208Z")  
}
```

Query written in MongoDB  :

```
aggregation query:
db.getCollection('employee_details')
    .aggregate([
        { $match: { department: "Product Management" } },
        {
            $group:
            {
                "_id": "$years_in_job",
                total: { $sum: '$salary' }
            }
        }
    ])
```

Comment: Did it work or still having issues ? If it did please accept this & that your question will be closed with an working answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you remove the $ in the salaries first and prepend it or concatenate it later after the total value has already been computed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
db.getCollection('employee_details')
    .aggregate([
        { $match: { department: "Product Management" } },
        {
            $group:
            {
                "_id": "$years_in_job",
                /** get substring of salary which removes $ from string & then convert it into double for sum */
                total: { $sum: { $toDouble: { $substr: ["$salary", 1, -1] } } }
            }
        }
    ])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AUGeeHV3n05)